# How Do I Get a Box Slider To Work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

http://jsfiddle.net/pjeuv1x5/

```
$('#slider1').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true,
  pause: 2000
});

$('#slider2').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true,
  pause: 3000,
  slideMargin: 20
});

<h3>Slideshow 1</h3>
<ul id="slider1">
  <li><img src="http://g.espncdn.com/s/Streak/12/logo.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://g.espncdn.com/s/Streak/12/logo.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://g.espncdn.com/s/Streak/12/logo.png" /></li>
</ul>

<h3>Slideshow 2</h3>
<ul id="slider2">
  <li><img src="http://g.espncdn.com/s/Streak/12/logo.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://g.espncdn.com/s/Streak/12/logo.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://g.espncdn.com/s/Streak/12/logo.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

I've been trying to get a box slider for my site but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Every time I try it, I get this result. What gives?!

Comment: your jsfiddle does not even have the bxslider plugin added

Comment: <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Where would I add that? ^^

Comment: I added them in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjeuv1x5/1/ (See __External resources__ on the left). But... it's working! Maybe something else is wrong. Open your console (F12) and tell us if you see any errors.